# Does A-Frame/Google Chrome have proper link traversal in 2019?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, aframe, webvr

Earliest information I could find on this was from 2017.

I have multiple pages linked in A-Frame but whenever the user goes to the next page it kicks them out of VR Mode. Is link traversal supported well in 2019 or am I missing something? Is it possible for the user to go from page to page in VR without being kicked out?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    <a-scene>
    <a-assets>
        <img id="box" src="img/white.jpg">
        <img id="stroke" src="img/stroke.png">
        <img id="cityhall" src="img/cityhall.jpg">
         <img id="clock" src="img/clock.jpg">
        <img id="titanic" src="img/titanic.jpg">
        <img id="logo" src="img/logo.png">
        <img id="shadow2" src="img/radial-shadow-2.png">
        <img id="background" src="img/360background.jpg">
    </a-assets>
```

```
    <a-image radius="5.7" position="0 -5 0" src="#shadow2" rotation="-90 0 0" scale="6 6 6"></a-image>

    <!-- CURSOR ENTITY -->
    <a-entity rotation="-10 0 0" position="0 0 0">
        <a-entity id="camera" camera look-controls rotation="0 0 0" wasd-controls>
            <!-- MAIN CURSOR -->
            <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; maxDistance: 500; timeout: 3000;" id="cursor-main" position="0 0 -2" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusOuter: 0.04; radiusInner: 0.03; thetaLength: 360; thetaStart: 90;" material="color: #439DC2;">
                <a-animation begin="cursor-fusing" attribute="geometry.thetaLength" fill="forwards" from="360" to="0" easing="ease-in"></a-animation>
                <a-animation begin="mouseleave" attribute="geometry.thetaLength" fill="backwards" from="0" to="360" dur="0"></a-animation>
            </a-entity>
            <a-entity id="cursor-loader" position="0 0 -2.0001" geometry="primitive: ring; radiusOuter: 0.04; radiusInner: 0.03;" material="color: #2ADD2A;">
            </a-entity>
        </a-entity>
    </a-entity>

    <a-sky src="#background"></a-sky>

</a-scene>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't work. Link traversal WebVR specification is only supported by Firefox, Samsung Internet, Oculus Browser and Supermedium.